# c++ using range based to access the vector wrapped in a shared_ptr gives unexpected result

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have the following code, why is the range based output is not what is stored in the vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

shared_ptr<vector<double>> get_ptr() {
    vector<double> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return make_shared<vector<double>>(v);
}

int main() {
    auto vec = get_ptr();
    for (int i = 0; i<get_ptr()->size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << (*get_ptr())[i] << std::endl;
    }
    for (auto v: (*get_ptr())) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output on my ubuntu is something like below,

```
1
2
3
4
5
4.67913e-310
4.67913e-310
3
4
5
```

Comment: Just wondering, how often are you calling `get_ptr()` there?

Comment: why you keep calling that function instead of using **vec** ?

Comment: Replacing all the calls to `get_ptr()` except for the first one should fix the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `get_ptr()` you create a new and unique copy of the vector. And that object will be destructed as soon as the full expression involving the call is finished.

So in the case of

```
for (auto v: (*get_ptr()))
```

As soon as `*get_ptr()` is finished, the object will be destructed.

And due to how [ranged for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) works, you will iterate using a non-existing vector, leading to *undefined behavior*.

---

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior,  [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is equivalent as

```
{
   init-statement
   auto && __range = range-expression ;
   auto __begin = begin-expr ;
   auto __end = end-expr ;
   for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin)
   {
      range-declaration = *__begin;
      loop-statement
   }
}
```

For `auto && __range = range-expression ;`, in your code it'll be `auto && __range = (*get_ptr()));`. `get_ptr()` returns by-value, what it returns is a temporary which will be destroyed after the full expression. After that `__range` is dangling. Any dereference on it leads to UB.

Even for the 1st code snippet, `get_ptr()` creates new `vector` every time when it's called in `if` condition and every iteration. It works just because `get_ptr()` always creates `vector` containing same elements and accessing them by index is fine.

Since C++20 we can use [temporary range expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Temporary_range_expression) for such temporary lifetime issue.

Answer (score 0):

A range-for loop behaves as if initializing the range to iterate over by a declaration of the form

```
auto&& range = range-expression;
```

where `range-expression` is the expression after the `:`. In your case:

```
auto&& range = (*get_ptr());
```

`get_ptr` returns by-value and therefore this creates a temporary `std::shared_ptr` holding the vector. You then dereference it and `range` will reference the managed vector. However, a temporary lives only until the end of the full-expression in which it was created and therefore the `std::shared_ptr` returned from the function is immediately after this line destroyed and it will take the managed vector with it since there is no other `std::shared_ptr` referring to it.

So the actual loop then uses the `range` reference which is now however dangling, causing undefined behavior.

Since C++20 there is an alternative syntax for range-for loops which allows you to store the temporary return value for the purpose of the loop, avoiding this common pitfall.

```
for (auto r = get_ptr(); auto v : *r) /*...*/
```